# PHP searching table then showing more then one result

Tags: php, search

I am trying to create a search, anyways my site is:

```
mysite.com/?p=search&t=[SEARCH VARIABLE]
```

So for in my case if my url is that I want it to search through my table of posts and give me the results where `[SEARCH VARIABLE]` exists in the table. Mainly I want it to check these columns: title, content and author. If there is any [Search variable] in there I want it to show up.

Attempt that works [with only 1 column] but does not give me all the results.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['t']))
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `title` like :t');
    echo ' <h1>Search results for: '.$_GET['t'].'</h1> ';
    if (!$stmt->execute(array(':t' => $_GET['t'])))
    {
        exit('Could not exec query with param: '.$_GET['t']);
    }

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo '<font size="4pt">'.$row["title"].'</font><br>';
    }
}
?>
```

My attempt the same as the first one but checks the content field. Does not work either.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['t']))
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `title` like :t AND `content` like :t;');
    echo ' <h1>Search results for: '.$_GET['t'].'</h1> ';

    if (!$stmt->execute(array(':t' => $_GET['t'])))
    {
        exit('Could not exec query with param: '.$_GET['t']);
    }

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo '<font size="4pt">'.$row["title"].'</font><br>
    }
}
?>
```

With the first one, it only shows one field with the title of it. But I want it to show anything with the word in it. For example if you search for "hey' and have "hey theres apples", i want it to show that hey theres apples.

EDIT:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['t']))
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `title` like %:t%');

    echo ' <h1>Search results for: '.$_GET['t'].'</h1> ';

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo '<font size="4pt">'.$row["title"].'</font><br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Still needing help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the wildcard `%` when you bind the parameter, not in the query.  Try the following (for the first code snippet):

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['t']))
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `title` like :t');
    echo ' <h1>Search results for: '.$_GET['t'].'</h1> ';
    if (!$stmt->execute(array(':t' => "%{$_GET['t']}%"))) // <---------- Added % here
    {
        exit('Could not exec query with param: '.$_GET['t']);
    }

    ...
}
?>
```

**Update** (For `or` condition with same value):

You cannot use the same named parameter twice in the same query.  Try the following:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['t']))
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `title` like :t or content like :content');
    echo ' <h1>Search results for: '.$_GET['t'].'</h1> ';

    $param_array = array(':t' => "%{$_GET['t']}%", ':content' => "%{$_GET['t']}%")
    if (!$stmt->execute($param_array))
    {
        exit('Could not exec query with param: '.$_GET['t']);
    }

    ...
}
?>
```

Comment: How would I be able to add OR `content` into it as well? Tried changing it to `$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `title` like :t OR `content` like :t');` Although it only picks up the title ones.

Comment: @user3124460, you cannot use the same named parameter twice in the same query.  Use a different name for `content` and assign the same value to `content`'s parameter.

Comment: Actually I got it working with it in the same query.                       `$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `title` like :t OR `content` like :t OR `content` like :t');`

Comment: @user3124460, Thanks for pointing that out.  This hadn't worked for me when I used it not too long ago.  Might have been PHP version.  Thanks for the confirmation that it works, I need to try it out. :)

Comment: Yeah, I actually thought it didn't work either. Guess it did.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `LIKE` clause:

- It has to be quoted
- and you should use `%` properly

An example:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `title` LIKE '%:t%' -- :t appears anywhere in title
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `title` LIKE ':t%'  -- :t is at beginning of title
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `title` LIKE '%:t'  -- :t is at the end of title
```